# Singular points of equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity

We have the linear differential equation

$$9x^2y''+9xy'-(1+x)y=0.$$

I want to determine and characterize the singular points of the equation in $\mathbb{R}$.

I have done he following.

A Sturm-Liouville problem has the following form.

$$-(p(x)\phi'(x))'+q(x) \phi(x)=\lambda \phi(x), x \in [a,b].$$

If $p$ gets zero at some point, then the Sturm Liouville problem is singular.

$$(x^2 y')'=2xy'+x^2 y''$$

$$9x^2 y''=9(x^2 y')'-18 xy'$$

So, $9(x^2y')'-9xy'-(1+x)y=0$.

Can this be writtenin the form of the Sturm-Liouville problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead take your original equation and divide by $x$. You get:

$$9xy’’+9y’-(1+1/x)y=0.$$

Now notice the first two terms are $(9xy’)’$. Can you finish from here?